# stat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'follow_symlinks'

Tags: python

Web search found links to bugs, I don't write complicated code on Python, just want to confirm I understand syntax:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

`Path.stat(*, follow_symlinks=True)`¶

But when I write `Path(filepath).stat(follow_symlinks=False)` I'm getting "stat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'follow_symlinks'" error. `lstat()` in place of `stat(follow_symlinks=False)` does job done.

Python 3.8.5. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading it correctly. You just missed the footnote. From [the page you linked](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.stat)

> *Changed in version 3.10: The follow_symlinks parameter was added.*

So if you want to use that keyword argument, you need Python 3.10 or newer. Otherwise, as you've already figured out, just use `lstat`.